# Running in background timer

Tags: android, service, timer

I have a timer but I want it to also run in the background, I created a new `Service`, I think it works but I have a problem with it, I want also to change the `layout` attributes, like changing `TextView` text using `setText` method, I prefer doing it with `BroadCastReceiver` so I have the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("SOME_ACTION");
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            textView.setText("hey");
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LocalService.class));
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```

I registered here the `Receiver` so it will happen when I am broadcasting from the `Service` and change the text to "hey" - I wanted it just to check if the broadcast is working. on the `Service` I used a code that runs a timer and when it start it will broadcast the message, it is the first time I am using `broadcasting receiver` for sending `actions` and not just to wait until `Bluetooth` is on and stuff like this, here is my `Service` code:

```
public class LocalService extends Service
{
    private static Timer timer = new Timer();

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        startService();
    }

    private void startService()
    {
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new mainTask(), 0, 5000);
    }

    private class mainTask extends TimerTask
    {
        public void run()
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction("SOME_ACTION");
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: I don't see a question in your post, but why don't you bind to the service to get the timer values? Sending broadcasts are pretty expensive.

Comment: @JonTom My question is why the textView is not changing, oops :P why is this code not working, and I don't understand what you mean by binding to the service to get the timer values.

Comment: Take a look at the docs about bound services: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html. You can bind to a service in the Activity's onCreate, pass the activity as a listener to the service and call the Activity's methods right from the service without any need in broadcasting.

Comment: If you still want to use BroadcastReceiver, I recommend using LocalBroadcastManager. Local broadcasts are restricted to the process of your app and are more efficient. Example is given here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8875292/837714

Comment: @JonTom Thank you very much!